# How to get url params from failed login attempt

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a grails site (grails 2.0 with spring security 1.2.6) login that's supposed to redirect depending on what parameters are passed in through the URL.

For example, if you went to `'/'` you would go to the standard `'login/auth'` but if you went to `'/?org=abccorp'` you would be redirected to `'landing/index'`. Once you log in successfully you'll be taken to different parts of the site based on the params passed in through the url and security role.

So far I have been able to get everything working in a normal scenario where someone logs in successfully. My problem comes from if someone fails the login, spring security redirects to the default `'login/authfail'` action with no way of finding the original url or parameters.

Supposedly there's a way to get these things but everything I've found has either been deprecated, moved or is simply not there.

Is there a way to get what params were originally passed in? Can I save them off somewhere between calls or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `authenticationFailureHandler` bean uses a `org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy` instance to do the redirect when login fails. This is by default a `org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy` instance and is registered as the `redirectStrategy` bean. So you could replace the `redirectStrategy` bean for the `authenticationFailureHandler` bean with your own. It doesn't look like it'd be practical to replace the whole `redirectStrategy` bean since you don't have access to the `Authentication` so you wouldn't know whether it was a failure or success redirect.

To avoid redefining the whole `authenticationFailureHandler` bean, I'd just change the bean in `BootStrap.groovy`. It'd be something like this (I haven't tested this so it might be off a bit)

```
import com.foo.bar.MyRedirectStrategy

class BootStrap {

   def authenticationFailureHandler

   def init = { servletContext ->
      authenticationFailureHandler.redirectStrategy = new MyRedirectStrategy()
   }
}
```

where `MyRedirectStrategy` is a custom subclass of `DefaultRedirectStrategy` (in src/groovy or src/java) that uses the request url to determine the redirect url.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be some kind of class I could extend. To get what I wanted, I had to add the parameter to the login form url (`/j_spring_security_check?foo=blah`), then pass it along in the url in my subclass of `DefaultRedirectStrategy`.